# Count size-k connected components in an undirected graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

Given an undirected graph of size `n`. How to count how many size `k` connected components are there in the graph? Assume `k<=n`, and that the input graph is connected.

For example, given a graph of `[(0,1), (1,2)]`. It has `3` size 1 connected components, `2` size 2 connected components, and `1` size 3 connected components.

Answer (score 0):

i think your problem is the exact same thing in [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/119935/is-there-an-algorithm-to-find-all-connected-sub-graphs-of-size-k) (this is about finding all connected subgraphs size k and the time complexity is n ^ k)

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. But the algorithm there is simply iterating all `n` choose `k` subsets of vertices and check if they are connected. I feel like there should be a more efficient algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

In case you are still interested, your problem is solvable in O(n*(d-1)^k), with d the degree of your graph, by picking a node N, and then adding nodes from its neighbors iteratively until reaching k nodes.

If efficiency is a thing to you, there is [this paper](https://consystlab.unl.edu/Documents/StudentReports/TR-UNL-CSE-2013-0005.pdf) proposing another algorithm for exactly your problem.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the iterative O(n*(d-1)^k) algorithm?